Mobile Push Notification Cloud Services In Saudi Arabia
I wanted to integrate Push Notification for mobile app but there is a government guideline in which Push Notification Cloud Server must be hosted in Saudi Arabia region only.
Can anyone suggest any Push Notification service provider in Saudi Arabia those Cloud Server hosted in Saudi Arabia.
Thanks

Hi @salman, So you could not use firebase? any updates on this issue?
